# ion-img display issue on Android device

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am displaying an image in a modal.
It works fine on web but on an Android device it only intermittently shows the image (otherwise it shows a no image placeholder).
If I get closing and reopening the modal / image by clicking on the thumbnail, about 25% of the time it shows the image ok.

I figure its something to do with the async loading of the base64 image data I am passing in as a parameter.  The page renders before it is loaded I guess. Any ideas to fix this?

Modal call:

```
 <ion-col size="3" *ngFor="let image of check.images">
  <ion-thumbnail>
     <ion-img [src]="image" (click)="onViewImage(image)"></ion-img>
  </ion-thumbnail>
 </ion-col>

constructor(private plt: Platform,
              private fileOpener: FileOpener,
              public defectReportService: DefectReportService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private socialSharing: SocialSharing,
              public storage: Storage,
              private notificationService: NotificationService,
              public modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private navCtrl: NavController
              ) { }

onViewImage(imageDataUrl: string) {
this.modalCtrl.create({
    component: ViewImageComponent,
    componentProps: { imageDataUrl: imageDataUrl }
  }).then(modalEl => {
    modalEl.present();
  });
```

}

Modal code:

```
 <ion-content class="content-modal">
  <div class="content-inner">
      <ion-img [src]="imageDataUrl" (click)="onCloseModal()"></ion-img>
  </div>
</ion-content>


export class ViewImageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() imageDataUrl: string;

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onCloseModal() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the code that opens the modal.

Comment: Have added the code that opens the modal

Comment: I also tried adding an ngIf and got the same issue.  Image works about 1/6 times.  So maybe not to do with loading the param data.
<div *ngIf="imageDataUrl" class="content-inner">
      <ion-img [src]="imageDataUrl" (click)="onCloseModal()"></ion-img>
  </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed using the NavParams solution here:

https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/how-to-declare-and-use-modals-in-ionic-v4-4d3f42ac30a3

The code below works 100% of the time:

```
export class ViewImageComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() imageDataUrl: string;
  imageDataUrl2: string;

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private navParams: NavParams) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.imageDataUrl2 = this.navParams.get('imageDataUrl');

  }

  onCloseModal() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

}


<ion-content class="content-modal">
  <div *ngIf="imageDataUrl2" class="content-inner">
      <ion-img [src]="imageDataUrl2" (click)="onCloseModal()"></ion-img>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Oh and the weird thing is if you use this code with the local variable the same name as the parameter that is passed to the modal it will not work properly, same intermittent problem.  So don't do that.